# Accessing data from C++ function into UITextView controller

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a question guys. 
I need to assign value to UITextView controller in my iPad app from a C++ function. So, the C++ function return a string and I can see that output in the output window. I merged C++ and XCode objective C by using .mm file. Now, I need to get the value from C++ function and add them in the UITextFiled.

Say for example. 
My C++ function is like the following:
.cpp file

```
void *consumer (void* data)
{
SyncBuffThang<GLOBAL_BUFF_LEN,GLOBAL_BUFFS>* cc =(SyncBuffThang<GLOBAL_BUFF_LEN,GLOBAL_BUFFS>*) data;

affinity("consumer", cons);

for (int ii=0; ii<100; ii++)
{
    unsigned char c = cc->get();
    cc->res = c;
    myVar = c;
    cerr << "Consumer Get" << myVar << endl;
    f +=c;
}

cerr << "Leaving consumer in method cons" << f  << endl;

return 0;
}


int PC9::RunPC()
{
SyncBuffThang<GLOBAL_BUFF_LEN, GLOBAL_BUFFS> pc;

pthread_t p, c;

pthread_create(&p, 0, producer, &pc);

pthread_create(&c, 0, consumer, &pc);

pthread_join(p, 0);

pthread_join(c,0);
}
```

And the following sows the .mm file code.

```
#import "PC.h"
#import "PC9.h"
#import "GV.h"

@implementation PC

-(void)callFunctionPC
 {
      PC9   * myCPlusPlusObj; //A C++ object
      myCPlusPlusObj=new PC9();
      myCPlusPlusObj-> RunPC();
  }

 @end
```

See in the above function I can print the myVar but, I don't know how to access it or view it on UITextFile from my iPad app.

Friends I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

-T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer I've been waiting for!!!

HelloWorld.h

```
  #ifndef __Demo1__HelloWorld__
  #define __Demo1__HelloWorld__
  #include <iostream>
  #endif 

  class HelloWorld {

  public:
      std::string Mtd_HelloWorld();
  };
```

HelloWorld.cpp

```
   #include "HelloWorld.h"
   std::string HelloWorld::Mtd_HelloWorld()
    {
       std::string output;
       output = "This is from C++";
       return output;
     }
```

HelloWorldM.h

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   @interface HelloWorld_M : NSObject
   -(NSString *)CallCPP;
   -(UIView *)CreateTextView:(NSString *)input;
   @end
```

HelloWorld.mm

```
    #import "PCViewController.h"
    #include "HelloWorld.h"
    #include "HelloWorld_M.h"
    @implementation HelloWorld_M
   -(NSString *)CallCPP
     {
      HelloWorld    * myCPlusPlusObj; //A C++ object
      myCPlusPlusObj=new HelloWorld();
      std::string res = myCPlusPlusObj-> Mtd_HelloWorld();
      NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:res.c_str()
                                            encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
      return result;
      }

     -(UIView *)CreateTextView:(NSString *)input
      {
      UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0.0,0.0,320.0,200.0)];
         myTextView.text = input;
         return myTextView;
       }

      @end
```

PCViewController.h

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     #import "HelloWorld_M.h"

     @interface PCViewController : UIViewController
      {
        HelloWorld_M *objHelloWorld;
       }
    - (IBAction)RunHelloWorld:(id)sender;
     @end
```

PCViewController.m

```
   #import "PCViewController.h"

   @interface PCViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation PCViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)RunHelloWorld:(id)sender
     {
      objHelloWorld = [[HelloWorld_M alloc]init];
      [self.view addSubview: [objHelloWorld CreateTextView:[objHelloWorld CallCPP]]] ;
       }
  @end
```